# Is there a stackoverflow/reddit/slashdot PHP clone that supports CQRS?

Tags: php, cqrs

CQRS means Command Query Responsibility Segregation.

Comment: I am looking for open source php code samples in order to study the architecture

Comment: I m really curious about your requirement to support CQRS, is it the scalable aspect you are interested in? If you are looking for CQRS samples look at https://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin and https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r both c# but it should give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at Quench but it does not respect CQRS